# How to optimize Project Euler's 12th problem (find first triangle number to have 500 divisors)?

Tags: python, optimization

I am a newbie in the coding world. I was trying to solve the 12th problem of Project Euler to find first triangle number to have 500 divisors.

My code returns result in around 17s. I am sure there are ways to run it in a lot shorter time. Can anyone help in optimizing my code?

Here is my code:

```
def divisor_triangle_numbers(div):
    tr_num = 1
    n = 2
    while True:
        tr_num += n
        divs = 0
        for i in range(1,int(tr_num**0.5)+1):
            if tr_num%i == 0:
                divs += 2
                if divs > div:
                    print(tr_num, divs)
                    return tr_num, divs
        n += 1
```

Comment: If you have a list of primes handy, you can finesse it a bit by counting how many times each prime goes into the test by factoring it, and multiplying all that together.  (eg, 12 is = 2^2 * 3^1.  Each factor can appear or not up to the power. three  possibilities for 2: (2^0, 2^1, 2^2), and two possibilities for 3 (3^0, or 3^1) = 6 divisors.  This takes a lot more code and accessory data though.

Answer (score -3):

You can try multithreading. It's not really optimisation but as it's fairly simple in python it may be a good easy improvement.